# docker pull gives invalid reference format

Tags: docker

I am doing a very simple job of creating a registry in one vm pushing hello-world with my tag, mentioned first vm's ip:5000 as insecure registry in next vm and trying to pull from my first vm registry.
It is giving me error  invalid reference format
don't understand what is wrong here, my commands are below

on first vm

```
docker pull hello-world
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry
docker tag hello-world localhost:5000/my-hello
docker push localhost:5000/my-hello
```

on second vm (used --engine-insecure-registry 192.168.99.100:5000 while creating)

```
docker pull 192.168.99.100:5000/my-hello
```

this gives me error

**Note**: I am able to curl to docker registry with below urls successfully

```
curl http://192.168.99.100:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["my-hello"]}
curl http://192.168.99.100:5000/v2/my-hello/manifests/latest
this gives me json response
```

Note: I am running all this behind proxy but I am able to pull from docker hub on both vms. Also in second vm when I do docker info, I get below result in the end

```
Insecure Registries:
 192.168.99.100:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: at home without proxies, things work fine

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I did some workaround and was able to solve my issue, mentioning it as answer to my own question cos that might help others.
I did port forwarding in virtualbox from my host and used my host ip as registry server. This not only did the trick to solve my issue but also helped me accessing my registry from other systems.